# Creating a conda virtual environment that conforms to an old version of Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to find a way to install a second version of Anaconda (with all the associated packages) or alternatively create an virtual environment that exactly conforms to an old version of Anaconda (specifically Anaconda 4.2 / python 3.5).

Context:
While I am personally working on a relative up to date version of Anaconda (2021.05), I am doing a workshop for a company that still works on Anaconda 4.2. To ease the creation of the workshop, I would like to code some exemplary code in jupyter notebook with the exact base environment of Anaconda 4.2. However, I seem to be unable to set up such an virtual environment without running in all kinds of compatibility issues. I feel like there has to be an easier way than reinstalling Anaconda every time I switch projects or alternatively to use conda and pip jointly to hack together a bunch of relevant packages in the correct versions (which currently always results in compatibility issues). Asking the company to move to a newer version is not really an option.

Some more details:
My main issue stems from the lack of old versions of pandas, numpy, matplotlib, and scikit learn in the default channels of anaconda, forcing me to install those versions with pip, which then results in compatibility issues.

Comment: Have you tried to specify the `free` channel additionally to the default ones?

Comment: Hey thanks, that already helped a lot. It seems to work now. Is there a way through which you can easily get the specifications of a given version of anaconda so that you do not have to type up all the versions in their documentation (e.g. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/old-pkg-lists/4.2.0/py35/)

Comment: Yes there is, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anaconda 5.0, there was a change in recipes/compilers and all packages that were available prior to that change are now in the `free` channel, which is not in the defaults to increase the speed of `conda`.

Since you want to have a rather old version of anaconda, you will need to add it. In order to get all packages that came alongside `anaconda-4.2.0`, you can simply use the `anaconda` metapackage. I.e. to create an environment that corresponds to anaconda 4.2, simply do:

```
conda create -c free -n anaconda42 anaconda=4.2.0
```

which correctly installs these packages:

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _license-1.1               |           py35_1          56 KB  free
    _nb_ext_conf-0.3.0         |           py35_0          929 B  free
    alabaster-0.7.9            |           py35_0          11 KB  free
    anaconda-4.2.0             |      np111py35_0          16 KB  free
    anaconda-clean-1.0.0       |           py35_0          42 KB  free
    anaconda-client-1.5.1      |           py35_0         166 KB  free
    anaconda-navigator-1.3.1   |           py35_0         3.1 MB  free
    argcomplete-1.0.0          |           py35_1          84 KB  free
    astroid-1.4.7              |           py35_0         258 KB  free
    astropy-1.2.1              |      np111py35_0         6.1 MB  free
    babel-2.3.4                |           py35_0         4.8 MB  free
    backports-1.0              |           py35_0           1 KB  free
    beautifulsoup4-4.5.1       |           py35_0         125 KB  free
    bitarray-0.8.1             |           py35_1          57 KB  free
    blas-1.0                   |              mkl           6 KB  free
    blaze-0.10.1               |           py35_0         622 KB  free
    bokeh-0.12.2               |           py35_0         3.4 MB  free
    boto-2.42.0                |           py35_0         1.5 MB  free
    bottleneck-1.1.0           |      np111py35_0         191 KB  free
    cffi-1.7.0                 |           py35_0         130 KB  free
    chest-0.2.3                |           py35_0           5 KB  free
    click-6.6                  |           py35_0         100 KB  free
    cloudpickle-0.2.1          |           py35_0          17 KB  free
    clyent-1.2.2               |           py35_0          15 KB  free
    colorama-0.3.7             |           py35_0          19 KB  free
    comtypes-1.1.2             |           py35_0         220 KB  free
    configobj-5.0.6            |           py35_0          28 KB  free
    console_shortcut-0.1.1     |           py35_1          47 KB  free
    contextlib2-0.5.3          |           py35_0          12 KB  free
    cryptography-1.5           |           py35_0         331 KB  free
    curl-7.49.0                |           vc14_0         305 KB  free
    cython-0.24.1              |           py35_0         2.2 MB  free
    cytoolz-0.8.0              |           py35_0         243 KB  free
    dask-0.11.0                |           py35_0         624 KB  free
    datashape-0.5.2            |           py35_0          94 KB  free
    decorator-4.0.10           |           py35_0          12 KB  free
    dill-0.2.5                 |           py35_0          75 KB  free
    docutils-0.12              |           py35_2         674 KB  free
    dynd-python-0.7.2          |           py35_0         435 KB  free
    entrypoints-0.2.2          |           py35_0           6 KB  free
    et_xmlfile-1.0.1           |           py35_0          15 KB  free
    fastcache-1.0.2            |           py35_1          27 KB  free
    filelock-2.0.6             |           py35_0           8 KB  free
    flask-0.11.1               |           py35_0         139 KB  free
    flask-cors-2.1.2           |           py35_0          16 KB  free
    freetype-2.5.5             |           vc14_1         621 KB  free
    get_terminal_size-1.0.0    |           py35_0           4 KB  free
    gevent-1.1.2               |           py35_0         471 KB  free
    greenlet-0.4.10            |           py35_0          16 KB  free
    h5py-2.6.0                 |      np111py35_2         656 KB  free
    hdf5-1.8.15.1              |           vc14_4         1.5 MB  free
    heapdict-1.0.0             |           py35_1           5 KB  free
    icu-57.1                   |           vc14_0        34.2 MB  free
    idna-2.1                   |           py35_0         115 KB  free
    imagesize-0.7.1            |           py35_0           3 KB  free
    ipykernel-4.5.0            |           py35_0         126 KB  free
    ipython-5.1.0              |           py35_0         1.0 MB  free
    ipython_genutils-0.1.0     |           py35_0          33 KB  free
    ipywidgets-5.2.2           |           py35_0          59 KB  free
    itsdangerous-0.24          |           py35_0           8 KB  free
    jdcal-1.2                  |           py35_1           9 KB  free
    jedi-0.9.0                 |           py35_1         195 KB  free
    jinja2-2.8                 |           py35_1         300 KB  free
    jsonschema-2.5.1           |           py35_0          97 KB  free
    jupyter-1.0.0              |           py35_3           3 KB  free
    jupyter_client-4.4.0       |           py35_0         141 KB  free
    jupyter_console-5.0.0      |           py35_0          69 KB  free
    jupyter_core-4.2.0         |           py35_0         104 KB  free
    lazy-object-proxy-1.2.1    |           py35_0          27 KB  free
    libdynd-0.7.2              |                0         3.9 MB  free
    libpng-1.6.22              |           vc14_0         547 KB  free
    llvmlite-0.13.0            |           py35_0         6.2 MB  free
    locket-0.2.0               |           py35_1           6 KB  free
    lxml-3.6.4                 |           py35_0         1.6 MB  free
    markupsafe-0.23            |           py35_2          28 KB  free
    matplotlib-1.5.3           |      np111py35_0         6.2 MB  free
    menuinst-1.4.1             |           py35_0         107 KB  free
    mistune-0.7.3              |           py35_0         131 KB  free
    mkl-11.3.3                 |                1       110.0 MB  free
    mkl-service-1.1.2          |           py35_2          10 KB  free
    mpmath-0.19                |           py35_1         897 KB  free
    multipledispatch-0.4.8     |           py35_0          12 KB  free
    nb_anacondacloud-1.2.0     |           py35_0          23 KB  free
    nb_conda-2.0.0             |           py35_0          28 KB  free
    nb_conda_kernels-2.0.0     |           py35_0          30 KB  free
    nbconvert-4.2.0            |           py35_0         358 KB  free
    nbformat-4.1.0             |           py35_0         159 KB  free
    nbpresent-3.0.2            |           py35_0         502 KB  free
    networkx-1.11              |           py35_0         1.1 MB  free
    nltk-3.2.1                 |           py35_0         1.8 MB  free
    notebook-4.2.3             |           py35_0         5.2 MB  free
    numba-0.28.1               |      np111py35_0         1.9 MB  free
    numexpr-2.6.1              |      np111py35_0         142 KB  free
    numpy-1.11.1               |           py35_1         2.8 MB  free
    odo-0.5.0                  |           py35_1         219 KB  free
    openpyxl-2.3.2             |           py35_0         253 KB  free
    openssl-1.0.2j             |           vc14_0         5.1 MB  free
    pandas-0.18.1              |      np111py35_0         6.9 MB  free
    partd-0.3.6                |           py35_0          25 KB  free
    path.py-8.2.1              |           py35_0          47 KB  free
    pathlib2-2.1.0             |           py35_0          28 KB  free
    patsy-0.4.1                |           py35_0         370 KB  free
    pep8-1.7.0                 |           py35_0          67 KB  free
    pickleshare-0.7.4          |           py35_0           9 KB  free
    pillow-3.3.1               |           py35_0         983 KB  free
    pip-8.1.2                  |           py35_0         1.6 MB  free
    pkginfo-1.3.2              |           py35_0          73 KB  free
    ply-3.9                    |           py35_0          72 KB  free
    prompt_toolkit-1.0.3       |           py35_0         308 KB  free
    psutil-4.3.1               |           py35_0         228 KB  free
    py-1.4.31                  |           py35_0         127 KB  free
    pyasn1-0.1.9               |           py35_0          57 KB  free
    pycosat-0.6.1              |           py35_1          80 KB  free
    pycparser-2.14             |           py35_1         152 KB  free
    pycrypto-2.6.1             |           py35_4         481 KB  free
    pycurl-7.43.0              |           py35_0          89 KB  free
    pyflakes-1.3.0             |           py35_0         119 KB  free
    pygments-2.1.3             |           py35_0         1.3 MB  free
    pylint-1.5.4               |           py35_1         347 KB  free
    pyopenssl-16.0.0           |           py35_0          68 KB  free
    pyparsing-2.1.4            |           py35_0          72 KB  free
    pyqt-5.6.0                 |           py35_0         4.4 MB  free
    pytables-3.2.2             |      np111py35_4         1.5 MB  free
    pytest-2.9.2               |           py35_0         282 KB  free
    python-3.5.2               |                0        30.3 MB  free
    python-dateutil-2.5.3      |           py35_0         237 KB  free
    pytz-2016.6.1              |           py35_0         171 KB  free
    pywin32-220                |           py35_1        10.4 MB  free
    pyyaml-3.12                |           py35_0         118 KB  free
    pyzmq-15.4.0               |           py35_0         498 KB  free
    qt-5.6.0                   |           vc14_0        51.2 MB  free
    qtawesome-0.3.3            |           py35_0         153 KB  free
    qtconsole-4.2.1            |           py35_2         201 KB  free
    qtpy-1.1.2                 |           py35_0          22 KB  free
    requests-2.11.1            |           py35_0         665 KB  free
    rope-0.9.4                 |           py35_1         237 KB  free
    scikit-image-0.12.3        |      np111py35_1        17.6 MB  free
    scikit-learn-0.17.1        |      np111py35_1         3.5 MB  free
    scipy-0.18.1               |      np111py35_0        11.7 MB  free
    setuptools-27.2.0          |           py35_1         761 KB  free
    simplegeneric-0.8.1        |           py35_1           7 KB  free
    singledispatch-3.4.0.3     |           py35_0          13 KB  free
    six-1.10.0                 |           py35_0           8 KB  free
    snowballstemmer-1.2.1      |           py35_0          79 KB  free
    sockjs-tornado-1.0.3       |           py35_0          33 KB  free
    sphinx-1.4.6               |           py35_0         1.3 MB  free
    spyder-3.0.0               |           py35_0         2.9 MB  free
    sqlalchemy-1.0.13          |           py35_0         1.4 MB  free
    statsmodels-0.6.1          |      np111py35_1         4.7 MB  free
    sympy-1.0                  |           py35_0         6.4 MB  free
    toolz-0.8.0                |           py35_0          80 KB  free
    tornado-4.4.1              |           py35_0         595 KB  free
    traitlets-4.3.0            |           py35_0         124 KB  free
    unicodecsv-0.14.1          |           py35_0          20 KB  free
    vs2015_runtime-14.0.25123  |                0         1.9 MB  free
    wcwidth-0.1.7              |           py35_0          21 KB  free
    werkzeug-0.11.11           |           py35_0         335 KB  free
    widgetsnbextension-1.2.6   |           py35_0         1.1 MB  free
    win_unicode_console-0.5    |           py35_0          27 KB  free
    wrapt-1.10.6               |           py35_0          38 KB  free
    xlrd-1.0.0                 |           py35_0         182 KB  free
    xlsxwriter-0.9.3           |           py35_0         192 KB  free
    xlwings-0.10.0             |           py35_0         741 KB  free
    xlwt-1.1.2                 |           py35_0         157 KB  free
    zlib-1.2.8                 |           vc14_3         111 KB  free
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       385.1 MB
```